# Modal is re rendered on onchange

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

Modal is re-rendering when I am typing something in the textfield. The modal then reopens, this only happens when I am typing.

```
    const [categoryData, setCategoryData] = useState({
      title: "",
      description: "",
      isActive: false,
    });

   handlerModuleInputs() {
   switch(pageName){
   case "":
    <List sx={{ mb: 5 }}>
                  <TextField
                    id="filled-basic"
                    label="Description"
                    type={"name"}
                    variant="filled"
                    value={categoryData.description ? categoryData.description : " "}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      setCategoryData({
                        ...categoryData,
                        description: e.target.value,
                      });
                    }}
                    style={{ width: "130ch" }}
                  />
                </List>
   }
   }     
   <Dialog
          disableAutoFocus={true}
          fullScreen={true}
          open={openModal}
          onClose={handleClose}
          
        >
        <DialogContent>{handlerModuleInputs()}</DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
```

Please refer the above code and help it

Comment: Are you opening modal on a state?

Comment: no i am not opening modal as your saying

Comment: where is the code to open modal? can you please add it.

Comment: const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);  const handleClickOpen = (e) => {
      setOpenModal(true);
    };
<Button
                  onClick={handleClickOpen}
                  style={{
                    marginTop: "0px",
                    // marginRight: "5px",
                    backgroundColor: "brown",
                    color: "white",
                  }}
                  variant="outlined"
                >

Comment: can you add the full source?

Comment: i have edited above code can see it now thanks